# Trying to pass mulltiple IDs into an API query

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, api

i'm running into trouble with a function I made in Angular and pulling data from an API. I want to expand a current part to accept more than one ID, but I run into an issue when I try and fetch more than one id to put into the API query.

```
if (this.selectedCustomer !== null) {
  filterString += `&customer_id=[${this.selectedCustomer.id}]`;
}
```

This returns `&customer_id=[1]` but what I want to achieve is this: `&customer_id=[1,2,3]`

Here is the replacement code I have written where I tried to list the IDs in an array and pass them through the query but the loop isn't working and the ids are coming up as 'undefined'

```
if (this.selectedCustomer !== null) {
  const customerIds = this.selectedCustomer.id.customerIds;
  for (let i = 0; i < customerIds; i++) {
    customerIds[i].selected = this.selectedCustomers.indexOf(customerIds[i].value) > -1;
  }
  this.selectedCustomer.id = customerIds;
  filterString += `&customer_id=[${customerIds + ','}]`;
}
```

If you can offer any help or point out what i'm doing wrong it would be highly appreciated! :)

Comment: The question is unclear to me. Are you building the query _to_ the API? Or are you treating data received _from_ the API? Which API, your own or a third party? What is the response format (JSON etc?) Can you post an example of the data to work with?

Comment: It's an API that's already built. Currently, I can use the filter "&customer_id=[1]" but I want to pass in all ID's from 'this.selectedCustomer.id' not just one. It should end up like "&customer_id=[1,2,3]"

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that :

```
const customerIds = this.selectedCustomer.id.customerIds.map(c => c.value); // Gives you [1,2,3]

filterString += "&customer_id=" + JSON.stringify(customerIds); // "&customer_id=[1,2,3]"
```

Comment: When I try that I get the following error: `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

Comment: Ah well, I'm missing info then. You are the one using `this.selectedCustomer.id.customerIds` in your code, I have no idea of its value and where it came from

Comment: Thats just code I put together to see if it would get my desired result. The first code works, but I need to expand it to pull in a range of ids instead of a single id

Comment: Yes, I got that, hence my answer to get `&customer_id=[1,2,3]`. Isn't that what you need?